# Cutdown Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: python, date, deadlines

I can not do it in the form such that it has deducted the time from today to an example; 2021: 04: 05 in the form of hours: minutes: seconds

```
from datetime import datetime, time



leaving_date = datetime.strptime('2021-04-05 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.now()

print(str"%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds")
```

Could someone improve my code and help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will give you hours, minutes and seconds as a string each:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = str(now).split(" ")[1].split(".")[0].split(":")
```

Comment: how to print this ?

Comment: I don't know which version of Python you're using. If it's >= 3.6, then `print(f"{hours} hours, {minutes} minutes, {seconds} seconds")` will do the trick.

Comment: I also, but these variables are not defined so how to print this lol

Comment: Because I want the script to count down time to the next day, for example, Date 2021: 04: 05 and I want to give how many hours: minutes: the second has been until that day